# JFileChooser with additional JCheckBox for setting the file opening method

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am using `JFileChooser` as a component for selecting files [in this code](https://github.com/kulvait/KCT_den_file_opener/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kulvait/kct/imagej/denfileopener/Den_File_Opener.java).

I need one additional input from the user to trigger the way how the file shall be opened. In my use case if it shall be read to the RAM entirely or not.

I know I can ask user elsewhere but the best would be if I can add `JCheckBox` to the `JFileChooser` dialog. I want to achieve something as on the picture.

[image]

How I can do that and how I read the status of user input?

Comment: How can you do that? You could try copying the source code for JFileChooser into your own file, and tinkering around from there. Me? I'd just launch a 2nd dialog via JOptionPane before or after the JFileChooser to get this extra bit of information

Comment: Agree with above comment or maybe just have the checkbox on the panel where you click the button to display the file chooser.

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#accessory Providing an Accessory Component is a way to go. They state: 'aside from a previewer, probably the most common use for the accessory component is a panel with more controls on it such as check boxes that toggle between features'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the simplest is to utilize the mechanism that is intended for image thumbnails of selected files. By providing so called Accessory Component, which must be a child class of `JComponent`, through calling `JFileChooser.setAccessory`  you can obtain a space to the right of file selecting rectangle.

Including minimal example:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setDialogTitle("Open DEN file...");
fc.setAccessory(new CheckBoxAccessory());
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
CheckBoxAccessory cba = (CheckBoxAccessory)fc.getAccessory();
boolean useVirtualStack = cba.isBoxSelected();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("selected=%b", useVirtualStack));
```

where the class CheckBoxAccessory looks as follows

```
public class CheckBoxAccessory extends JComponent {
    JCheckBox virtualCheckBox;
    boolean checkBoxInit = false;
    
    int preferredWidth = 150;
    int preferredHeight = 100;//Mostly ignored as it is  
    int checkBoxPosX = 5;
    int checkBoxPosY = 20;
    int checkBoxWidth = preferredWidth;
    int checkBoxHeight = 20;
    
    public CheckBoxAccessory()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(preferredWidth, preferredHeight));
        virtualCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Virtual stack", checkBoxInit);
        virtualCheckBox.setBounds(checkBoxPosX, checkBoxPosY, checkBoxWidth, checkBoxHeight);
        this.add(virtualCheckBox);
    }
    
    public boolean isBoxSelected()
    {
        return virtualCheckBox.isSelected();
    }
}
```

The result looks as follows
[image]

Disadvantage is that you will not get the whole component to play with but just a relatively small box. Thus the visual look is not what I initially wanted, but when you are no Picasso, you won't care. Advantage of this solution is that you can even react on change of selected file, which is in more details described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#accessory